# I can't connect to my websocket because its handshake Sec-WebSocket-Accept header value is incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm doing my first test, trying to use a **phpwebsocket**.

I set its handshake `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header value to the following:

```
$accept=base64_encode(SHA1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", true));
/* $key has $buffer value */
```

So I run the websocket php file (that creates a connection), as all okay.

So I run my test html that contains a script that try to connect to the phpwebsocket that I'm using, and in browser console I get this error:

```
fc.js:43 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/PetStack/inc/server.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value
```

But I found this [Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590412/error-during-websocket-handshake-incorrect-sec-websocket-accept-header-value), which is solved by defining **buffer limit**, would be my problem that?

I don't understand how to define the **buffer limit**, but case it's my problem, please explain me.

It wasn't me that made this phpwebsocket, I'm just using it.

Well, this is the line of variable `$upgrade` in a phpwebsocket file, that sets some headers.

```
                "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n".
                "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n".
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
                "WebSocket-Origin:{$origin}\r\n".
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:".$accept."\r\n\r\n".
                "WebSocket-Location: ws://{$host}{$resource}\r\n\r\n".
                chr(0);
```

Comment: Now I'm using substr to get Sec-Websocket-Key and keep in my variable `$key`;   `$key=substr(substr((string)$buffer,strpos

((string)$buffer,'Sec-WebSocket-Key:')),strpos((string)$buffer,' 

')+1,strpos((string)$buffer,'=')+1);` - but I still get the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your handshake looks weird.

There is not `Websocket-Origin` or `Websocket-Location`headers, and you are doing a double break line between the last two.

Your response should look more like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
```

So try something like this:

```
"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
"Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n".
"Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$accept}\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help, but I still get the error... :( The line looks `$upgrade="HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
"Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" .
"Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$accept}\r\n\r\n";`.

Comment: It looks the error wasn't in this line, but probably may affect. This error means that my Sec-WebSocket-Accept key is invalid.

Comment: can you put an example of request you get and response you return?

Comment: I already tried to remove them, but here's it: (I'll add in few comments)

Comment: I mean the actual HTTP request and response

Comment: The response in Xampp shell is: `2015-11-02 12:40:55 System: Socket Resource od #7 created.
2015-11-02 12:40:55 System: Socket bound to localhost:8000.
2015-11-02 12:40:55 System: Start listening on Socket.
2015-11-02 12:42:12 WebSocket: Resource id #8 CONNECTED!
2015-11-02 12:42:12 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\MegamanStack\inc\socketWebSocket.class.php on line 119
2015-11-02 12:42:12 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2015-11-02 12:42:12 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2015-11-02 12:42:12 WebSocket: Resource id #8 disconnected`